# Difference between two yield statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

What would be the difference between the following two generator functions?

```
def get_primes(number):
    while True:
        if is_prime(number):
            number = yield number
        number += 1
```

And:

```
def get_primes(number):
    while True:
        if is_prime(number):
            yield number
        number += 1
```

As far as I understand, I can call them as:

```
p = get_primes(0)

# first call works for both
next(p) # or p.send(None)

# second call different for both
next(p)    # works for second way only
p.send(14) # works for first way only
```

I think my issue is I don't really understand how `send` works and how it's setting the value and all.

Comment: The first one allows you to `send` a new value for `number`, and *fails* if you don't. If you call `next` without sending a value, then `number` will be `None` and then `number += 1` raises a TypeError.

Comment: @kaya3: Though it could be made to work fairly easily by accepting into a different name, and only moving it to `number` if the value sent was non-`None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send), it says:

> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function. The *value* argument becomes the result of the current yield expression.

That may sounds a little cryptic, so perhaps in other words:

Using `send()` the generator resumes where it yielded and the value you have sent is what `yield` returns (and can be assigned to any variable). You can also try the following code:

```
def get_num():
    number = 1
    while True:
        print(number)
        number = yield number

g = get_num()
g.send(None)  # haven't yielded yet, cannot send a value to it
g.send(2)
g.send(5)
```

It'll return:

- `1`: value we've initially assigned to `number`
- `2`: we did `send(2)` and that is what `number = yield ...` assigned to `number`, then we continued, looped back to `print()` and yielded again.
- `5`: Same thing, but we did `send(5)`.

Comment: cool, can also examine what it's storing by doing `g.gi_frame.f_locals`.

Comment: Also -- to clarify, it **first** returns the yield statement and **after** assigns the value from send to number, correct?

Comment: Yes, it yields and suspends there. Using `send() ` the generator resumes with `yield` returning (having, inside the generator) sent value and continues execution until it yields again (or ends).